# I''m fairly new to ReactJs and I'm trying to render an image file that the user chooses. But I'm failing miserably

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm trying to update the setInitialState variable, but I'm getting an error("Invalid value for prop `src` on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM."). Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
export function Passport()
{

    var[intialState, setInitialState] = useState('')

    const fileSelector = (event) => 
    {
      setInitialState = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
      console.log(setInitialState)
    }

   return(    
        <Container>  

                <Row>        
                    <Col md={{ span:4, offset:5 }}>        
                        <input type = "file" onChange= {fileSelector}   />
                    </Col>

                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col md={4}>
                     <h1> Image area</h1>  
                     <img src = {setInitialState}/>                     
                  </Col>

                  <Col md={{ span: 4, offset: 4 }}>
                    <h1> Form area</h1>
                  </Col>    

                </Row>       
        </Container>

    );


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInitialState` is the function handler that changes the state. You need to pass the value of state `initialState` to src.

```
<img src = {initialState}/>
```

Also you are changing the state incorrectly. In your fileSelector do

```
const fileSelector = (event) => 
{
  setInitialState(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]))
 // console.log(setInitialState)//
}
```

React docs says -

> useState returns a pair: the current state value and a function that lets you update it. You can call this function from an event handler or somewhere else. It’s similar to this.setState in a class

Check out the docs to know more - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Comment: Silly me. Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: @YashGaur Glad to be of help. :)